# Wordpress loop is not showing all posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I got lots of articles I show on my category page.

Here is the code.

```
<?php if(is_category(4)) { 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="work">
            <div class="work-thumb">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="work-title">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop.
} ?>
```

It is just loop on all articles, but it doesn't show all of them, just like 50%

What could be the problem>?

Answer (score 2):

Is the page that's using that template/code the page that you have set to be the Posts Page, in admin settings?

If so, then the posts per page setting could be less than the total number of posts (and you would need pagination, or to increase this number).

If it's a custom query with the code in your question, then you need to add this to the query arguments:

```
'posts_per_page' => -1
```

Note: Even if your case is the former, you could alter the query by using the `pre_get_posts` filter. E.g. put this in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_filter');

function my_filter( $query ){
    $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
    return $query;
}
```

Inside that function, you want to wrap the code inside an `if` statement, to do it specifically for the, for example, post type or taxonomy in question.

Comment: I have no limits on my loop, but it shows last 150 posts. I dont need pagination, i want to show all of them on one page

Comment: It is not at admin page. it is category.php

Comment: You'll then still need to apply one of the two latter fixes in my answer. Are you using a custom query? If yes, could you paste it into your question? If the code in your question is all the code that is in the template file, then you'll need to use the `pre_get_posts` hook method